# How to dynamically read field from ctypes structure

Tags: python, ctypes

I have a ctypes structure with many fields which works wonderfully, but when trying to dynamically read a field I can't figure out how to do it.

Simplified example:

```
from ctypes import *
class myStruct(Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ("a", c_int),
        ("b", c_int),
        ("c", c_int),
        ("d", c_int)
    ]

myStructInstance = myStruct(10, 20, 30, 40)

field_to_read = input() #user types in "c", so field_to_read is now set to "c"
print(myStructInstance.field_to_read) #ERROR here, since it doesn't pass the value of field_to_read
```

This gives an attribute error "AttributeError: 'myStruct' object has no attribute 'field_to_read'

is there a way to dynamically get a field from a ctypes structure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getattr(obj,name)` is the correct function to look up an attribute on an object:

```
from ctypes import *
class myStruct(Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ("a", c_int),
        ("b", c_int),
        ("c", c_int),
        ("d", c_int)
    ]

myStructInstance = myStruct(10, 20, 30, 40)

field_to_read = input() #user types in "c", so field_to_read is now set to "c"
print(getattr(myStructInstance,field_to_read))
```

Answer (score -1):

How about `dataclass` and `eval()`?

**sample**

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass
from ctypes import *

@dataclass
class MyStruct:
    a: c_int
    b: c_int
    c: c_int
    d: c_int


my_struct_instance = MyStruct(10, 20, 30, 40)

field_to_read = input()
print(eval(f"my_struct_instance.{field_to_read}"))
```

**Output example**

> > b
>   20

Comment: Hmm... Seems interesting, thank you very much. What does the dataclass decorator do? my python version doesn't support it since it's pretty new, and it seems like the solution would work without it as well. (P.S. thank you for changing my variable names, i have unfortunately not yet burned PEP8 into my memory yet -- friendly reminders always welcome)

Comment: You are able to use `dataclass` with [Python 3.7+](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html).  It defines the field data, and so on.

Comment: `eval` is unsafe for user input.  Input can be crafted to do Bad Things™.  Use `getattr()` instead.